# C# Add strings together

Tags: c#

im making a speech alias program. Im trying to make it to add commands.
You know basically to make a array of strings you do
string mystring = "string1","string2";
How am I able to add it just like ,"string3" to make it
string mystring = "string1","string2","string3";
Here is my code:

```
List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();
            myCollection.Add("hello");
            myCollection.Add("test");
            string final = string.Join(",", myCollection.ToArray());
            richTextBox1.AppendText(final);
            sp.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(new String[] { "" + final }))));
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are running into?

Comment: @CodingYoshi when I do that I do not get 2 seprete strings. I get 1 string like hello,test

Comment: You should read [ask] and then edit your question, based on the [ask] page, to make it clearer to understand.

Comment: Are you asking for `string[] finals = new [] { "hello", "test" }`?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes but thats not the format the string is coming out in I need those 2 strings to be coming out sepertly not as 1 string. The strings need to seperate so this code looks like this. sp.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(new String[] { "hello","test" }))));

Comment: @loganrisen but it's already separate and you join them. So why do you join them?

Comment: @CodingYoshi I need to convert it to a string and thats they only way I figured out...

Comment: "I need those 2 strings to be coming out sepertly not as 1 string" … "I need to convert it to a string". Which? Do you need it to be separate strings or do you need to convert it to a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API you are calling requires an array of `string`. If you know how many strings you will be passing, then do not use a `List<string>`. This will help you avoid having to convert `List<string>` to a `string[]`. This is how it will work:

```
var myCollection = new string[2];
myCollection[0] = "hello";
myCollection[1] = "test";
sp.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(myCollection)));
```

If you are not sure how many strings you will be passing then use a `List<string>` like this:

```
var myCollection = new List<string>();
myCollection.Add("hello");
myCollection.Add("test");
```

Then you need to convert a `List<string>` to a `string[]`, just call `ToArray<string>()` on your collection like this:

```
var myCollectionAsArray = myCollection.ToArray();
sp.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(myCollectionAsArray))));
```

---

**What do you mean by if you know how many strings you will be passing?**

If you were checking some dynamic condition (a condition only known at runtime) to add items to the choices collection, then you will need a `List<string>`. For example:

```
var myCollection = new List<string>();

myCollection.Add("hello");
if (someCondition)
{
    // this will only be known at runtime
    myCollection.Add("test");
}
```